# Copy documents from one DocumentCollection to another?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, document-database

In my **Azure CosmosDB**, that I use with the **Gremlin API** there is one database called *graphdb* with several {DocumentCollections}. 
I would like to copy a selected set of Vertices and Edges from one collection (*graphdb*) to another (*Tintin*).

[image: My Azure CosmosDB]

I managed to do this by transferring all data via the client, but it would be much easier if data stayed in Azure. Thus I tried some SQL in the **Azure portal** like:

```
SELECT *
INTO Tintin 
FROM graphdb;
```

However, this seems unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you cannot join multiple collections and you query violates this rule.

But I think +1 for your idea, you should post it on https://feedback.azure.com/